# Evaluating an Integral in the form of $\int e^{1/x}\;dx$

Tags: integration

So I stumbled upon this integral solving a problem:$$\int e^{1/x}\;dx$$I tried substitution and integration by parts but they kept looping round and turning into dead ends.

So I adopted a new method of approach and my plan was to take advantage of the series expansion of $e$. Here is my working:
$$\int e^{1/x}\;dx=\int\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(1/x)^n}{n!}dx=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{n!}\int x^{-n}dx=-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{n!}\cdot \frac{x^{-n+1}}{n+1}=-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(1/x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$Let  $k=n+1$
$$\implies-\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(1/x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(1/x)^{k}}{k!}=-\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\left(\frac{(1/x)^{k}}{k!}\right)-1\right)=-\left(e^{1/x}-1\right)=1-e^{1/x}$$

This integral doesn't look right and Wolfram Alpha is talking about $\text{Ei}$ functions. I do not see any error in my logic so I am confused on why this answer is such.

Comment: $x^{-n+1}$ isn't $(1/x)^{n+1}$. And $-n+1$ isn't $n+1$.

Comment: clever, i come to the same conclusion. i have done an integration before and used wolfram alpha to verify and it gave me the same type of thing the Ei function, but when i reviewed my logic and definitions i came to the conclusion WA was just not accounting for something that it should have. those are my thoughts i agree with your answer and work.

Comment: some algebra errors sure but approach is fine

Comment: You should *know* it is not correct because if you differentiate $1-e^{1/x}+C$ you do not get $e^{1/x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change of variables $u=1/x$ and integration by parts
$$\int e^{1/x}dx = -\int \frac{e^u}{u^2}du = \frac{e^u}{u} - \int \frac{e^u}{u}du
=\frac{e^u}{u} - \mathrm{Ei}(u) + C = xe^{1/x} -  \mathrm{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+ C
$$
Thus the answer given by WA is reproduced, with the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ defined for $x\ne 0$ by (Cauchy principal value integral if $x > 0$)
$$
\mathrm{Ei}(x) = -PV\!\!\!\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt = PV\!\!\!\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^t}{t}dt
$$

Comment: @amWhy: Some more info included with a link to Wikipedia, where the Cauchy PV is mentioned.

Comment: Now it's a fine answer! +1

Comment: Ahh I see! So the anti-derivative $\int \frac{e^u}{u}du$ cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions and therefore has it's own function the Exponential integral. I did this method too but I did not have knowledge of the Ei function and was stuck with logarithms and more substitutions till I gave up as the answer wasn't going anywhere. Thank you for your answer!